# Does a static variable reset after a time

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, lifetime

I have a simple access control class which allows to check a user has permissions, this then interacts with the static variable:

```
private static bool canUpdate = false;
```

This is used during the page load
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        AccessControl I = new AccessControl(parameter);

        canUpdate = I.HaveEdit;
    }
    BindGrid();
}
```

This all works just fine, it is simple and the bool is used as part of another method (called as a gridview code expression) in order to conditionally display a control in a row.
This also works just great.

However I am in a testing stage and I have realised that under normal operations everything is great, however after a time has passed (significant, like half hour or so), the buttons are no longer displayed (in other words the canUpdate has set to false).

The code for the display:

```
protected bool ShowNewStamps(object date)
{
    //Returns to Bind Expression whether to display Timestamp Link
    if (date == null & canUpdate == true)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

The date is passed in as a binding expression, passing in the date of the cell before, therefore I know this is not the issue.

The issue only presents itself when the page is refreshed after significant time, is this due to static variables having a lifetime and i am only setting the variable on first page load?

Comment: No, but the lifetime of a static variable is the same as its AppDomain. And if you use IIS then your AppDomains will be recycled eventually. To make it short: do not use static variables for web applications. Store information in the database or a session state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static` variables, like all other variables expire in some time. When that is usually depends on life time of the application pool in IIS.

I don't think that is the issue though. **`static` variables are shared across ALL SESSIONS.** That means that if someone else opens another session (or you by using another browser), you will reset that variable.

This kind of information should live in the `ViewState` or `Session`.

Lession learned: don't use `static` variables for information that is user, session or page specific.

Answer (score 3):

Static variables do not reset after some time.

Its most probably the IIS recycling your application and thus creating a new `AppDomain` and statics.

Answer (score 0):

static variables don't reset, except when you recycle application pool. difference between static and non static variable is when you define a static variable you can make sure that it will exist in life time of the application because they store in a heap by the name high frequency heap which is not under the control of GC. but in the case of non static variables GC controls existence of them.